# ServiceNow Chart Filtering

Tags: javascript, api, filter, servicenow, jchart2d

Our company's using ServiceNow to track incidents reported by users.  To keep an eye on call resolution our helpdesk look at a backlog chart to keep an eye on trends.  The backlog chart is produced using the same code as is available here:
http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Custom_Chart_Rendering

I was recently asked to look into filtering this graph by category, so that we can focus on incidents for particular applications.  I've tried a few options but can't find anything which successfully filters the data.  My best bet at present is that I need to apply the filters to the summary set, but even with admin access I'm unable to edit summary sets (I can't say if this is an issue with our setup or by design as I don't have much experience with this system / any with this API).

Thanks in advance for any pointers / suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Custom charts are great for rendering data that standard charts cannot, but you have to consider the data to be "cooked" once the summary set for that day (week/month/whatever) has been collected.

Meaning that you can't necessarily then break it down by category. To do so you would need to create additional summary sets for each category but the risk is then that someone will say "Hey, can you break that down by priority?"

Are you saying you cannot edit the summary set data or the generator? It makes sense that you can't hack the summary set data once it's cooked.